# Displaying unknown amount of data to screen

Tags: android

I have a sqlite database which contains multiple messages.

Each message has a

- Title
- Body
- Importance level (0/1/2)
- Possible calander _id

I want to display them to the screen in a scrollable list. Each list item can be clicked on which will then start another activity to edit the message.

I don't want direct code on how to do it, I'd prefer suggestions on how to do it so I can learn myself. If I need to give any extra info please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use adapter in your case `CursorAdapter` would be appropriate. There are many tutorials on internet about `CursorAdapter` and using it alongside with `SQLite`:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
https://coderwall.com/p/fmavhg/android-cursoradapter-with-custom-layout-and-how-to-use-it

A general note about Adapters is that they are a mean to transfer your data to appropriate View so you can populate your `ListView`, `GridView`, ... with the customized data. But this need a whole tutorial. You can also look to see how to work with different type of views which allow to be populated with Adapters.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give these a read, I didn't really know where to start or what to search for, which lead me to post here instead